# merge math, photography-calculations, and formula tags

Tags: discussion

The [math](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), [photography-calculations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography-calculations), and [formula](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula) tags all seem redundant. I'm not sure which one should be the canonical one (maybe just [calculations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculations), which doesn't exist?), but I don't think there's a good purpose for all three....

Comment: Formula can be other things too, not only math and calculations. No example comes to mind atm though.

Comment: Sure, technically a formula could be a process or method. But as used so far on the site, it's applied to mathematical formulas. For the other usage, there's the  somewhat-dubiously-vague but popular tag [tag:techinque].

Comment: eh, [technique](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) I presume.

Comment: Yes, you presume correctly. :)

Comment: Makes sense to me, and I agree that calculations is a good way to go with those.

Comment: Hey @chills42 (or other mods, but you replied), want to go ahead and do it?

Comment: Yeah, sounds good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like people are generally in favor. I went ahead and created a "[calculations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculations)" tag so that exists; now all that's required is for a mod to merge the other three tags into that.

Comment: They've been merged.

Comment: @chills42 Awesome, thanks!